# Canvas ocupar a tela inteira com css

Tags: css, html5, canvas

Tenho meu `canvas` no html5:

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

Quero que o canvas ocupe toda área disponível do browser, tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
canvas{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    Height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c33;
}
```

O `Width` está ocupando tudo, porém o `Height` não ocupa tudo. Tem como fazer ocupa todo espaço do browser?

Comment: Coloca no css uma referência para o html e body tags com um height de 100%. Isso deve resolver o problema

Comment: opa, obrigado, resolveu o problema, só uma pergunta: não há problema em deixar o `body` e `html` no `css` setado o `height`?

Comment: Nao, nao ha nenhum problema :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `height: 100%` só funcionam se usar `position: absolute` (ou `fixed`) ou [Quirck Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) (não é recomendável, sempre use um `doctype`).

Uma maneira de resolver seria assim (neste caso recomendo `fixed`, se você quiser ocultar o resto dos elementos):

```
#meuCanvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    Height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c33;
    position: fixed; /*ou position: absolute;*/
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}

<canvas id="meuCanvas"></canvas>
```